# how to save data in local database in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#

I was just refreshing my coding abilities. but unable to recall much, here i am to get your favourable assistance for continuing my interest with technology.

I am trying to practice in developing a local database while accessing through GUI of visual studio 2012 in dot net framework 4.

I using below code to insert the data in database which is been visible in data grid view but is not saving in database.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(global::dbpracticewddotnet4.Properties.Settings.Default.dbpractnet4ConnectionString);
con.Open();
string sql = "insert into practice (name,contact,email,username,password,access) values('"+txtname.Text+"','"+txtcontact.Text+"','"+txtemailid.Text+"','"+txtusrnm.Text+"','"+txtusrpswrd.Text+"',"+1+")";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
this.practiceTableAdapter.Fill(this.dbpractnet4DataSet.practice);

MessageBox.Show("added successfully.....","message",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

[image]

[image]

here i uploaded the screen shot of the result.
requesting to please assists on how could i work to save the data in database.

regards